# Why does the colour of all my objects change when i edit the base colour, even though i have multiple materials?

Tags: materials

I'm new to Blender. As you can see, there are two materials of different colours. This second cube is assigned to the second material and when I select the first cube it highlights the first material, which suggest to me that the two cubes are assigned different materials.

However, the second cube takes on the colour of the first material. Why?

[image]

Comment: there are 2 possibilities, either you haven't properly assigned the good material (go in Edit mode, select all and press Assign) or your 2 objects are linked duplication and in that case one will be modified when the other will be (or you need to unlink their material)

Comment: how did you create that second cube? By cloning or duplicating? Also as moonboots says, its because second cube have Material assigned and not Material.001, try to remove Material from second cube with - button or follow his idea

Comment: Thank you!, this worked

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/516/add-different-materials-to-different-parts-of-a-mesh